# How can I border each word in jquery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click http://jsfiddle.net/18zdmp4b/1/ to see result. Enter value in the input, press Enter key, the value will be border. However, I want to border each word alone. If I enter banana, apple and banana should be separate in two different rectangle. How can I achieve that? appreciate.

```js
$( "#input" ).keydown(function( event ) {

   //press Enter key
if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    
    //put input value into div
var value=$('#input').val();
    $('#test').append(" "+value);
   
   $('#test').css('border-style','solid');
     
}
    
    
});
```

```css
.test {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test">apple</div>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `value` on whitespace, loop over the words, and create individual HTML tags for each word.

```js
$( "#input" ).keydown(function( event ) {
    //press Enter key
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //put input value into div
        var value = $('#input').val();
        var words = value.split(/\s/);
        for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
            var word = words[i];
            if ( word ) {
                $('#test').append(' ');//Add the space between tags (optional).
                $('<span></span>')
                    .text(words[i])
                    .css('border-style','solid')
                    .appendTo('#test');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.test {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test">apple</div>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```